# error when installing wine from debian packages

Tags: command-line, wine

this is the error after i use   > `make depend`   command inthe command line

```
In file included from rtl.c:37:0:
../../include/winternl.h:991:11: error: duplicate member ‘s’
rtl.c: In function ‘RtlInterlockedFlushSList’:
rtl.c:976:29: warning: unused variable ‘newHeader’ [-Wunused-variable]
rtl.c:976:18: warning: unused variable ‘oldHeader’ [-Wunused-variable]
rtl.c: In function ‘RtlInterlockedPushEntrySList’:
rtl.c:999:29: warning: unused variable ‘newHeader’ [-Wunused-variable]
rtl.c:999:18: warning: unused variable ‘oldHeader’ [-Wunused-variable]
rtl.c: In function ‘RtlInterlockedPopEntrySList’:
rtl.c:1022:18: warning: unused variable ‘entry’ [-Wunused-variable]
rtl.c:1021:29: warning: unused variable ‘newHeader’ [-Wunused-variable]
rtl.c:1021:18: warning: unused variable ‘oldHeader’ [-Wunused-variable]
rtl.c: In function ‘RtlInterlockedPushListSList’:
rtl.c:1060:29: warning: unused variable ‘newHeader’ [-Wunused-variable]
rtl.c:1060:18: warning: unused variable ‘oldHeader’ [-Wunused-variable]
make[2]: *** [rtl.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/wine-1.1.27/dlls/ntdll'
make[1]: *** [ntdll] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/wine-1.1.27/dlls'
make: *** [dlls] Error 2
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please state what you are trying to achieve instead of just reproducing an error message. This is not a paid, customer support forum, but a free, voluntary, participative site. Please also explain what efforts you made to resolve the issue. Provide as much detail as possible for other users to "help" you.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to install packges in Ubuntu is:

```
sudo apt-get install [package name]
```

For install wine package:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Comment: no i can't 
this is the error
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package wine is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'wine' has no installation candidate

Comment: your ubuntu is 32bit or 64bit? | you can find out by "uname -r" command

Comment: kali linux 64 bit

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa -y && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine

Comment: no ican't do that command